Get request problem in production angular 18
Good morning
I am currently encountering the following problem, maybe someone has already encountered this problem.
The problem is only present in production and not locally
This is about my request get
The requests work, I recover the data but they are not up to date
There is some kind of recording when I perform an npm run build
my request get in production retrieves old data valid at the time of the npm run build, but does not take into account updates
To put it simply I can turn off my backend my request get still works but the data is of course not up to date
Do you know what this is due to?
Here is my website
https://www.chatterie-british-kingdom.fr/
Thank you for your time
Sincere
